# From query i wil get 2 rows but while returing the map i am not getting 2 rows i am getting only last row

Tags: java

// i created on method in that i am getting data from database through query , i am getting 2 rows but while returning the map i am not getting 2 rows it returning only last row

```
    public Map<Integer, String> getname(int id) {
                
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    //creating map
                Map<Integer,String> stylesMap = new LinkedHashMap <Integer,String>();
                try {
                    
           Query query=getSession().createSQLQuery("select distinct id,name from employee where id="+id);
                    
            List results = query.list();
            Iterator itr = results.iterator();
    //iterating the values
    
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
             Object row1[] = (Object[]) itr.next();
    //setting values into map
            stylesMap.put(row1[0]==null?0:Integer.parseInt(row1[0].toString()), (row1[1] == null)? "" : row1[1].toString());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("", e);
                } finally{
                    if(session !=null) {
                        session.close();
                    }
                }
// returning map
        return stylesMap;
```

}

Comment: Can you show us how the results look like ?

Comment: I meant the results varible `List results = query.list();`

Comment: if i print style map System.out.println("styleMap"+ styleMap). i am getting like this              stylesMap {7=2}

Comment: id name
7 1 
7 2                                                                                                                                     the query returns data like this

Comment: Since you are creating a map, for every key we will have only one value, the key for both the records is 7. In the first iteration, the map contained (7,1) and when you are adding the next value, since the key is same it will override the previous one

Comment: then how can i access  that data.....

Comment: You can use some other data structure to store this value other than map as map will require unique key.

You can store it in List<Pair<int,int>> or you can create a class(EmployeeDetails) which can stores id, name, and you can store this returned rows as List<EmployeeDetails>.

Comment: I also have one doubt, id should be unique, then two employees should not have the same id.

Comment: can you give any example

Comment: Added an example in the answer, do let me know if it helps

Comment: Hey @Chakravarthirudhir Reddy, Is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB returns two rows with data

```
7 1
7 2
```

You are trying to store this information in a map, but since a map stores only one value for a key, the first one will be overwritten.

If your DB contains two records for the same id( which ideally should not be the case), then you can store this information in

1. A list of [pairs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pair-class-in-java/), something like `List<Pair<int,int>>`
2. Or you can create an EmployeeDTO

   ```
   public class EmployeeDTO{
      String id;
      String name;
   }
   ```

   And you can store the results you got in a `List<EmployeeDTO>`